# Lua get function from argument

Tags: c++, lua

A simple example of producing.

```
protocol.onConnect(function() end, function () end, ...)
```

Now in c, i want to get the functions which are in args #1, #2.
In strings, numbers,... we can get them using (lua_getstring,..), But I at-least didn't found how to get a function.

```
int luaProtocolOnConnect(lua_State* L)
{
    int base_func // func #1
    int call_func // func #2
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot really "get" a Lua function. Lua functions, like Lua tables, are pure-Lua objects. As such, they have no C or C++ analog. If you want to call a Lua function, that's done through `lua_call`, `lua_pcall` or similar functions. This is done in-situ on the Lua stack.

So you can't take a Lua function and turn it into a C++ value. What you *can* do is take a Lua function and manipulate it in the various ways that all Lua objects can be manipulated.

For example, let's say you want to store a Lua function in a C++ object, then later call whatever Lua function was stored there. Well obviously, you can't convert the Lua function directly into a C++ value. What you *can* do is store that Lua function in a place which C++ can access. You use some value which *does* have a C++ analog to reference that stored Lua function. The value must be unique for every object you want to store like this. The value you get when storing the object will be saved in your C++ object. When the time comes to retrieve the Lua function, you simply use the stored value to retrieve it.

Because this is an exceedingly common operation, Lua has ways to facilitate this. The first is the Lua registry, a table that C++ can access but Lua code cannot (not unless you give it access).

The second is the `luaL_ref` series of functions. `luaL_ref` takes whatever is at the top of the stack and sticks it in a table you provide, returning to you an integer key that can be used to retrieve it later. `lua_rawgeti` can be used to retrieve the function from the table by the key, and `luaL_unref` takes the table and the integer key, removing the referenced function from the table when you're done with it.

So if you want to store such functions, you simply need to create such a table, stick it in a known place in the registry (so that you can fetch it whenever you need to), and then use `luaL_ref` to store those functions. When it comes time to call them, retrieve them with `lua_rawgeti`. When you're finished using them, destroy them with `luaL_unref`.

Comment: Something related: do you know if it is safe to store a reference to a `lua_State` received as an argument to a `CFunction`? Is there any risk the reference moves?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [lua_isfunction](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_isfunction) to check if it's a function, use `lua_pushvalue` to push its value on top of the stack and then use [luaL_ref](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_ref) (`luaL_ref(L,LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);`) to turn it into a unique key you can later reference to retrieve the value (`lua_rawgeti(L,LUA_REGISTRYINDEX,ref)`) and call the function.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to reference things directly into the registry. Not unless your code is the only C/C++ code that will execute within that Lua environment.

Comment: I generally agree, but in this case the key is guaranteed to be unique and I've seen some libraries doing this without issues (for example, winapi). OP may substitute their own table as needed.

Comment: It's only guaranteed to be unique "As long as you do not manually add integer keys into table `t`".

Comment: @NicolBolas, yes, but the registry is private to the C side, not accessible from the Lua side (unless the C side provides this access), so this is nothing more than the usual care you need to have with any data in a program. And the registry is intended to that purpose.